# Azure devops private nuget takes a long time to find package

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package

We are using Azure DevOps pipelines. We have a step that publishes the our private nuget package to the Azure Artifacts. However, the build breaks at other steps because the nuget package (that was published on previous steps) is not found. The strange thing is that after the package is published, I can see it in the package-manager console or on Visual Studio and even in the Artifacts in Azure DevOps. But for some reason, the pipeline doesn't find the package. After 30-50min, I re-run the pipeline and then it finds the package.

What could be happening to take so long time for the pipeline to find the my package?

**Edit 1:**

This is my yaml for the step with error

```
- script: |
        pwd && ls -la 
        dotnet restore "$(solution_path)" $(nuget_args)
        dotnet publish -c Release -o $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin "$(main_project_path)"
        mkdir artifact
        cp -r $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin artifact/bin
      displayName: Build Application
```

The error is:

> /data/vstsagent/user/389/s/src/MyProject.csproj
> : error NU1102: Unable to find package MyPackage with
> version (>= 2.1.0) [/data/vstsagent/user/389/s/src/MySolution.sln]
> /data/vstsagent/user/389/s/src/MyProject.csproj
> : error NU1102:   - Found 28 version(s) in MyPrivateRepository [ Nearest
> version: 2.1.0-preview.6 ]
> [/data/vstsagent/user/389/s/src/MySolution.sln]

Comment: Provide more info, such as your build yaml for the relevant jobs/steps

Comment: Thank you. Can you see my edit 1?

Comment: yes, that's where it's published, now show the following steps where you're trying to consume the package

Comment: I published the package on about three stpes earlier. In this snippet, I try to consume the package from the previous step. But I get this error "NU1102: Unable to find package". If I wait 1 hour, and re-run the failed step, the pipeline can find the package. Why take so long time for the pipeline to find my package? Theres cache?

Comment: Ah, the publish confused me.  Try running dotnet restore with —no-cache flag here

Comment: I was publishing in one pipeline and restored from my local, I can confirm it took a few minutes and recovered after a short break.  @Moho's -no-cache seems a fresh idea to try.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what feed is used by dotnet restore command.

1. Confirm that you have configured your custom  nuget feed in nuget.config and using it.
2. Try adding "--verbose" switch in dotnet restore command and check if your feed is used for restoring packages.

Comment: The correct switch is "-verbosity:<level>" or "-v:<level>" for short. d[etailed] of diag[nostic].

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--no-cache` option so [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) doesn't use the local cache.